# PHP MVC folder structure / Model-Folder-Structure

Tags: php, model-view-controller, model, structure, directory-structure

> The model is not a class or any single object. It is a very common mistake to make [...], because most frameworks perpetuate this misconception.

So, what is the best folder structure for the models?

The [Zend Recommended Project Directory Structure](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/project-structure.project.html), for example, has only a "model" folder. But when I try to separate my models into [Domain Objects, Data Mappers and Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863870/how-should-a-model-be-structured-in-mvc/5864000#5864000), how should this structure look like?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is subjective, but I will give you my way of doing it. I keep the `models` directory and then create different sub-directories for each module of the application. It would look something like the following:

```
application
  - controllers
  - models
     - authentication
         - services
         - mappers
         - ...
     - mail
         - services
         - mappers
         - ...
     ... (other directories)
  - views
  - templates
```

I feel this gives a nice separation of each module while keeping everything inside the `models` directory which other developers are properly used to.

I dont know if this is the best or most effective solution, but I think with proper use of namespaces it proves quite easy to manage. I have also learned that if you make proper use of the `SOLID principle` you can (almost) copy/paste the different directories/modules to other projects without much hastle.

[A little series created by TutsPlus, which explains the SOLID principle in detail by using theory and a concrete example.](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/solid-part-1-the-single-responsibility-principle--net-36074)

I hope this can help you the right direction.
Best regards.

Answer (score -1):

In Zend Framework you can create "modules" which can integrate their own models.

```
application/
    configs/
        application.ini
    controllers/
        helpers/
    forms/
    layouts/
        filters/
        helpers/
        scripts/
    models/
    modules/
         Domain Objects/
           controllers/
           models/
         Data Mappers/
           controllers/
           models/
         Services/
           controllers/
           models/
    services/
    views/
        filters/
        helpers/
        scripts/
    Bootstrap.php
```

As you can see, each module has also controllers and views associated.

Finally, you have to add these models to your bootstrap's autoloader :

```
// Admin
    $resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
        'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/Domain Objects',
        'namespace' => 'Domain Objects'
    ));

    $resourceLoader->addResourceType('controller', 'controllers/', 'Controller')->addResourceType('model', 'models/', 'Model');
```